# Can a debug=true directive be added to an ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm sure this has been asked before, but after numerous searches I can't seem to determine whether it's possible to put a single page in 'debug mode' in ASP.NET MVC.

In ASP.NET Web Forms, you can do one of the following (stolen from the yellow screen of death):

1) Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
```

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In this particular instance I'd like to be able to do the former, since I'd like more information on just one page, where there's an issue in the view.

Do I have to go the Web.config route instead, with ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in ASP.NET MVC you should use the corresponding section in web.config to determine the debug mode. Just make sure you don't ship with `debug="true"` in production as ASP.NET MVC does some optimizations like caching view locations based on this property. So as it name suggests use only in debug mode. You might also want to take a look at [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) when you ship in production.

Comment: So, there's no way to force a single page into debug mode in ASP.NET MVC, as we can in Web forms?

Comment: @James Skemp, the sole notion of *Page* no longer makes sense in ASP.NET MVC. What if you are using some other view engine? Like Razor for example?

Comment: You should be able to enable it for specific directories, at least. I'm not sure if you can do it per-file though. @Darin: I guess it could make sense to want to debug a certain view if the view is having problems. I don't see why he wants to avoid putting the entire site in debug mode though...

Comment: @Darin, Razor is what I'm using, actually. I suppose I just assumed that debug wasn't solely a Web forms view engine directive, as it can be set in the Web.config. @Matti Virkkunen, that's what I ended up doing in this particular case. It was the yellow screen of death that really made me question this, since that's still returned by Razor. (Also, the error only popped on production. It's not production enough that anyone is going to hit it when I switched it over, but ...)

Comment: @James Skemp, locally, in debug mode you can leave this option in web.config. But it is extremely important that your build process sets it to false or you might have some performance problems in production.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Which it of course does. Trust me, 'debug mode = bad in production' has been firmly cemented in my mind for the last handful of years. Otherwise I would have just updated the Web.config and not asked :D Answer is yours, once the site lets me accept it.

Comment: Razor always compiles views in debug mode by the way.

Comment: @Lukáš Novotný, really? Because if it is ELMAH wasn't letting me see the actual error. Instead, it was giving the standard 'turn on debug,' from which I copied the language for the two steps above. Source?

Comment: Yes. You can verify it by putting `#if DEBUG` directive in your view. However note that this is *view* only, controllers are still compiled with whatever configuration you specify before deploying your application. Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1625220.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks (and not that it matters, but +1). If I'm reading that correctly, it's a bug that should hopefully get fixed.

Comment: This did not work for me.  Nor for others, ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175224/asp-net-wont-compile-to-debug